# Macro VBA script

Tags: debugging, excel, visual-c++, vba

Can someone help me with this problem. I have this code but it doesn't work. Something is wrong it says "Sub or Function not define".

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim x As Integer, result As String

x = 2

' 1st row

Do While Cells(x, 4).Value = 1

      If Cells(x, 3).Value <= Cells(x, 2).Value And Not Cells(x, 4).Value < Cells(x, 1).Value Then
      result = "pass"

      Else
      result = "fail"

      End If
      Cell(x, 5).Value = result

      x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Cell` to `Cells` and it will work. Excel just wasn't being helpful enough with that error message. It does however select the text for Cell when you have the editor open and try to run it.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim x As Integer, result As String

x = 2

' 1st row

Do While Cells(x, 4).Value = 1

      If Cells(x, 3).Value <= Cells(x, 2).Value And Not Cells(x, 4).Value < Cells(x, 1).Value Then
      result = "pass"

      Else
      result = "fail"

      End If

      Cells(x, 5).Value = result

      x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```